# Azure Key Vault - Certificate generation

Tags: x509certificate2, azure-keyvault

I am using the following script to generate a new ROOT CA that will be used to generate sub-ca's and client certificates.

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation "cert:\CurrentUser\My" -Subject "CN=$certificateCleanName" -KeySpec Signature -KeyUsage CertSign -TextExtension @("2.5.29.19 ={critical} {text}ca=1")
```

This works perfectly, but I would prefer to generate them in the Key Vault Directly (via Powershell).
I know you can generate a self signed certificate in the key vault directly with this command:

```
$manualPolicy = New-AzureKeyVaultCertificatePolicy -SubjectName "CN=something.com" -ValidityInMonths 24 -IssuerName Self -RenewAtNumberOfDaysBeforeExpiry 100
$certificate = Add-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $vaultName -Name $certificateName -CertificatePolicy $manualPolicy
```

However, with the command above, I am not able to generate the exact same certificate properties as in the first command that use to generate the certificate locally.
Any idea how I can specify the following arguments to create the certificate with the exact same settings directly in the KeyVault?

```
-KeyUsage CertSign -TextExtension @("2.5.29.19 ={critical} {text}ca=1")
```